# Multiple type sorting swift 4

Tags: swift

I have a list of 4 comments which i want to sort according to the reply and the date.

```
let comment1 = Comment(content: "Comment1". date: "12daysAgo", subCommentOf: nil)

let comment2 = Comment(content: "Comment2". date: "5daysAgo", subCommentOf: nil)

let comment3 = Comment(content: "Comment3". date: "10daysAgo", subCommentOf: comment2)

let comment4 = Comment(content: "Comment4". date: "1daysAgo", subCommentOf: comment1)

let comment5 = Comment(content: "Comment5". date: "10daysAgo", subCommentOf: comment1)
```

so after sorting end result should be 5 cells in tableview
where

```
comment1 1st cell -> comment5 -> comment4 -> comment2 -> comment3
```

Comment is a Model where subComment is Comment optional

I have tried these so far

```
 let sortResults = thisComments.sorted {
                    let main0 = ($0.isSubComment != nil) ? 0 : 1
                    let main1 = ($1.isSubComment != nil) ? 0 : 1

                    if main0 < main1 {
                        return main0 < main1
                    }

                    return false
  }
```

Comment: What is `Comment`, and what does `subCommentOf:` mean in a table view?  What format are your input/output?  What operating system is this for?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Ssswift updated the question.

Comment: Two suggestions.  1. Usually a sort function is symmetric, so you'd want to handle the `>` the same as the `<` case.  You don't know what order it's going to pass the items to you.  2. It's hard to sort strings with structured data, especially relative dates.  Parse them first.  The model should generally hold data structures, not formatted text.

Comment: @Ssswift that sounds tough, can you suggest me the best way to handle comments, subcomments, sub sub comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to order your `Comment` objects like that, I'd add a `before` method (or whatever you want to call it) to `Comment` to see if it should show one `Comment` before or after another:

```
class Comment {
    let content: String
    let date: String
    let parent: Comment?

    init(content: String, date: String, parent: Comment?) {
        self.content = content
        self.date = date
        self.parent = parent
    }

    /// Determine order of comments
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - other: The other `Comment` I'm going to compare myself to.
    ///   - order: Whether I want to compare the numeric field in dates in ascending or
    ///            descending order (default, descending; i.e. older ones first)
    ///
    /// - Returns: Return `true` if this should be sorted before `other`.

    func before(_ other: Comment, dateOrder order: ComparisonResult = .orderedDescending) -> Bool {
        switch (parent, other.parent) {

        case (nil, nil):
            // if we are both top level comments), let's just compare our dates;
            // note use of `.numeric` option (to sort these strings in "1", "5", "10", rather than "1", "10", "5")

            return date.compare(other.date, options: .numeric, range: nil, locale: nil) == order

        case (let selfParent?, let otherParent?) where selfParent === otherParent:
            // if we are siblings, let's just compare our dates;
            // again, note use of `.numeric` option

            return date.compare(other.date, options: .numeric, range: nil, locale: nil) == order

        case (nil, _):
            // if I'm a top-level comment, but other comment isn't ...
            //    ... and this is my child, then I'm obviously before it
            //    ... otherwise let's see if I'm before the other comment's parent or not

            if self === other.parent! {
                return true
            } else {
                return before(other.parent!, dateOrder: order)
            }

        case (_, nil):
            // if I'm not top level comment, but other one is ...
            //    ... and I'm a child of the other one, then I'm obviously after it
            //    ... otherwise see if my parent is before that other comment

            if parent! === other {
                return false
            } else {
                return parent!.before(other, dateOrder: order)
            }

        default:
            // if we got there, we're apparently children of different parents,
            // so let's compare our respective parents.

            return parent!.before(other.parent!, dateOrder: order)
        }
    }
}

// useful extension if I want to `print` my `Comment` objects

extension Comment: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { return "<Comment; content=\(content); date=\(date); parent=\(parent?.content ?? "none")>" }
}
```

(Forgive me for renaming that `subCommentOf` property to something more common, such as `parent`. It just seems like a more logical name to me when trying to capture parent/child relationships between `Comment` instances.)

Anyway, you can then do something like:

```
let comment1 = Comment(content: "Comment1", date: "12daysAgo", parent: nil)
let comment2 = Comment(content: "Comment2", date: "5daysAgo",  parent: nil)
let comment3 = Comment(content: "Comment3", date: "2daysAgo",  parent: comment2)
let comment4 = Comment(content: "Comment4", date: "1daysAgo",  parent: comment1)
let comment5 = Comment(content: "Comment5", date: "10daysAgo", parent: comment1)

let comments = [comment1, comment2, comment3, comment4, comment5]
    .sorted { $0.before($1) }
```

Which results in:

```
"<Comment; content=Comment1; date=12daysAgo; parent=none>",
"<Comment; content=Comment5; date=10daysAgo; parent=Comment1>",
"<Comment; content=Comment4; date=1daysAgo; parent=Comment1>",
"<Comment; content=Comment2; date=5daysAgo; parent=none>",
"<Comment; content=Comment3; date=2daysAgo; parent=Comment2>"
```

Or, if you want them sorted in ascending order:

```
let comments = [comment1, comment2, comment3, comment4, comment5]
    .sorted { $0.before($1, dateOrder: .orderedAscending) }
```

Which yields:

```
"<Comment; content=Comment2; date=5daysAgo; parent=none>",
"<Comment; content=Comment3; date=2daysAgo; parent=Comment2>",
"<Comment; content=Comment1; date=12daysAgo; parent=none>",
"<Comment; content=Comment4; date=1daysAgo; parent=Comment1>",
"<Comment; content=Comment5; date=10daysAgo; parent=Comment1>"
```

---

Personally, I think the above is a hot mess (and it won't work for trees of comments and replies of arbitrary depth; to make it work in that scenario, we'd have to make it even messier) and I'd rather:

- I'd approach this the other way around, letting the comments keep track of their replies.
- As an aside, I find the representation of dates as "10daysAgo" vaguely discomforting, as the "how old is it" is a function of how to show the date the comment was created, not the property itself. I'd make `date` a `Date` type. If you need it, I'd add a `init` method that can convert, for example, a RFC 3999/ISO 8601 date string to a date. I'd also add a nice formatter to create the `howOld` string from the date for showing it in your UI.

E.g.:

```
class Comment {
    let content: String
    let date: Date
    var replies: [Comment]?

    private static var dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    private static var howOldFormatter: DateComponentsFormatter = {
        let _formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        _formatter.unitsStyle = .full
        _formatter.maximumUnitCount = 2
        _formatter.allowedUnits = [.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second]
        return _formatter
    }()

    init(content: String, date: Date, replies: [Comment]?) {
        self.content = content
        self.date = date
        self.replies = replies
    }

    init(content: String, date: String, replies: [Comment]?) {
        self.content = content
        self.date = Comment.dateFormatter.date(from: date)!
        self.replies = replies
    }

    var howOld: String { return Comment.howOldFormatter.string(from: date, to: Date())! }
}
```

Then the "give me a sorted list of all the comments and replies (and subreplies)" becomes a fairly trivial recursive function:

```
extension Comment {
    func isOrdered(_ rhs: Comment, order: ComparisonResult = .orderedAscending) -> Bool {
        return date.compare(rhs.date) == order
    }
}

extension Array where Element == Comment {
    /// Return simple recursively flatten array
    ///
    /// - Parameter order: The order you want them sorted. If not provided, it defaults to ascending order.
    /// - Returns: The recursively flattened array

    func flatten(order: ComparisonResult = .orderedAscending) -> [Comment] {
        return sorted() { $0.isOrdered($1, order: order) }
            .flatMap { comment -> [Comment] in
                if let replies = comment.replies {
                    return [comment] + replies.flatten(order: order)
                } else {
                    return [comment]
                }
        }
    }        
}
```

Or, if you want to keep track of what level of indentation each reply (and subreply) is:

```
extension Array where Element == Comment {
    /// Return recursively flattened array of tuples, (level, comment), where
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - order: The order you want them sorted. If not provided, it defaults to ascending order.
    ///   - level: The level to be used for top level objects. Generally you don't have to provide this.
    /// - Returns: The recursively flattened array of tuples, `(Int, Comment)`, where the `Int` is the level of indentation.

    func flattenTree(order: ComparisonResult = .orderedAscending, level: Int = 0) -> [(Int, Comment)] {
        return sorted() { $0.isOrdered($1, order: order) }
            .flatMap { comment -> [(Int, Comment)] in
                if let replies = comment.replies {
                    return [(level, comment)] + replies.flattenTree(order: order, level: level + 1)
                } else {
                    return [(level, comment)]
                }
        }
    }
}
```

And if I do:

```
let reply0   = Comment(content: "Comment6", date: "2017-11-04T00:00:00Z",  replies: nil)
let reply1   = Comment(content: "Comment4", date: "2017-11-02T00:00:00Z",  replies: nil)
let reply2   = Comment(content: "Comment5", date: "2017-11-01T00:00:00Z", replies: [reply0])
let comment1 = Comment(content: "Comment1", date: "2017-10-27T00:00:00Z", replies: [reply1, reply2])
let reply3   = Comment(content: "Comment3", date: "2017-10-01T00:00:00Z",  replies: nil)
let comment2 = Comment(content: "Comment2", date: "2017-09-14T00:00:00Z",  replies: [reply3])

let comments = [comment1, comment2]
    .flattenTree(order: .orderedAscending)
    .map { ($0.0, $0.1.content, $0.1.howOld) }

print(comments)
```

And that would report (at the the time I ran this):

```
[(0, "Comment2", "1 month, 26 days"),
 (1, "Comment3", "1 month, 9 days"),
 (0, "Comment1", "12 days, 18 hours"),
 (1, "Comment5", "7 days, 18 hours"),
 (2, "Comment6", "4 days, 18 hours"),
 (1, "Comment4", "6 days, 18 hours")]
```

Comment: this is amazing, although i ended up  *var hasSubComment:[Comment]*, which works pretty fine and was easier, what do you think?

Comment: @TestDjay - I personally wouldn’t use a `has` prefix in my property name or `init` method signature because to me that suggests a Boolean. (The use of auxilliary verb and preposition prefixes in `init` method signatures is more of an Objective-C convention and is a bit unswifty. In Swift, the parameter names of `init` methods are generally the exact names of the properties, themselves.) I’d lean towards simply using a plural nown, such as `subcomments` or `replies`, personally, because that suggests an array of objects. But obviously, feel free to use whatever you want.

Comment: done thanks, i wasn't actually looking for grammatical error haha, just wanted to know if my solution is easier/better or not :) thanks